# gsap&Angular - onComplete triggering function but can't change variable value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, gsap

I am using GSAP with my Angular project to implement animation on my custom dropdown menu.

I found that I could collapse my `div` down to `height: 0px`, however the border was still present.

My initial thought was to use `visibility: hidden` by means of using the Angular directive: `[hidden]="isHidden"` whereby `isHidden` is a declared variable in the `.ts` file initialised within the constructor.

I attempted to use the `onComplete` part of the `TweenMax.to(...)` to fire off a function that will toggle the `isHidden` to `true`/`false`. However, I found that I couldn't change the Boolean value from here?

I did check that the function fired with a `console.log(...)`, however I couldn't get the variable to change...

Am I doing something wrong?

```
visible: boolean;

constructor() {
  this.visible = false;
}

toggleDropdown(): void {
  TweenMax.to(dropdown, 1, {css: {height: '0px'}, ease: Power2.easeInOut, onComplete: this.toggleVisibility}
}

toggleVisibility() {
  this.visible = !this.visible;
}
```

Comment: if you console this.visible are you getting expected result inside toggleVisibility method?

Comment: Ahh, I get `undefined`

Comment: This tends to confirm my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I tried your answer below and it works wonderfully! Thanks for the advice :-)

Comment: Oh, awesome :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that, in the `toggleVisibility()` function, the context (`this`) is not the same as in `toggleDropdown()`, because you're not passing it along.

It's a tricky concept, but you have to pass/bind `this` to the function you call as a callback :

`..., onComplete: this.toggleVisibility.bind(this)`

Try to `console.log(this)` inside `toggleVisibility()` to see whether the context is correct or not.